# can redux saga dispatch return api result immediately instead of returning action

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

Given a dispatch below inside a Promise

```
Promise.resolve(this.props.dispatch(getAPI(item))) // dispatch
.then(function (result) { //result is the action passed in
    Linking.openURL(result.url);
})
```

once the dispatch executes and calls an api which then returns a value like a url can I immediately access the api result inside then()? so that I can immediately use the result and pass it into Linking.openUrl()

the reason I'm asking is because I can't seem to get the most recent props when the api result is sent to mapToProps. If I try using lifecycle methods like componentWillUpdate to force update the prop, it calls componentWillUpdate multiple times and while it does open the url, you can see it refresh multiple times on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the api you want to call is wrapped in a **promise**,

### Sagas.js

```
function * defaultSaga (action) {
  try {
    ... Other Code
    const result = yield call(YourApi, params) // Check the docs for redux-saga call
    // On api Success
    if(result && result.ok) {
      yield call(Linking.openUrl, result.url)
    }
  } catch(ex) {
    yield put(// Any error action here)
  }
}
```